# Bash: using xargs/parallel arguments in function for variable substituion

Tags: macos, bash, xargs

I've been struggling with this Bash script for about a week trying to do what seems like the simplest thing.  I'm using `fswatch` to watch a given folder and produce the filename of any single file added to it as output.  That output is piped to `xargs` which then runs a function with several commands that use the name of the file passed by `fswatch`/`xargs` with variable/argument substitution.

```
#!/bin/bash

compressor() {
    filepath="filepath"
    mkdir -m 777 /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath##/}_PROCESSING
    mv ${filepath} /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath##/}_PROCESSING
    /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -computergroup "This Computer" -jobpath /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath##/}_PROCESSING/${filepath##/} -settingpath /Users/lr/Documents/CONVERTHQTEST.cmprstng -locationpath /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath##/}_PROCESSING/${filepath%.*}.mp4
}

export -f compressor

/usr/local/Cellar/fswatch/1.8.0/bin/fswatch -0 -v --event Created --event MovedTo /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch |
    xargs -0 -n1 -I'filepath' bash -c compressor 'filepath'
```

In the simplest configuration, where I piped the output to `xargs` and used `xargs` to run a program using argument substitution, everything worked fine.  I then got a request to have the script create a new folder for each file added, move the file to that folder, then run the command.

With multiple commands nothing seems to work.  I can't get `xargs` to pass the arguments to the function so that the function can define a variable using the argument and do variable substitution within the filepath.  If I do `xargs -I'filepath' command 'filepath'` and then `filepath="filepath"` within the function, I end up with `mkdir` creating a file called `filepath_PROCESSING` rather than the argument from `fswatch` being substituted in.

How can I pass an argument to a function using `xargs`?

Comment: I've also tried this : `#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/Cellar/fswatch/1.8.0/bin/fswatch -0 -v --event Created --event MovedTo /Users/leftright/Desktop/Watch | parallel -0 -n1 -q -x -v 'mkdir -m 777 /Users/leftright/Desktop/Watch/"{/.}"_PROCESSING/ \; mv "{}" /Users/leftright/Desktop/Watch/"{/.}"_PROCESSING/ \; /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -computergroup "This Computer" -jobpath /Users/leftright/Desktop/Watch/"{/.}"_PROCESSING/"{/}" -settingpath /Users/leftright/Documents/CONVERTHQTEST.cmprstng -locationpath /Users/leftright/Desktop/Watch/"{/.}"_PROCESSING/"{/.}".mp4 \;'`

Comment: Obviously this is not very legible; if it's important to the question, it should be added via an edit so others can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: you are misunderstanding [how function arguments are passed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions). They are positional parameters (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc.) so your function could be defined something like this:

```
compressor() {
    filepath="$1"
    # define a variable rather than including this 5 times
    process="/Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath#/}_PROCESSING"
    mkdir -m 777 "$process"
    mv "$filepath" "$process"
    /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -computergroup "This Computer" -jobpath "$process/${filepath#/}" -settingpath /Users/lr/Documents/CONVERTHQTEST.cmprstng -locationpath "$process/${filepath%.*}.mp4"
}
```

Then, when you call `bash -c`, it's expecting a single argument (see note below) but you are passing it two. Try some quotes and it should work:

```
fswatch -0 -v --event Created --event MovedTo /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch |
    xargs -0 -n1 -I filepath bash -c 'compressor "filepath"'
```

> [`-c` will] read and execute commands from the first non-option argument after processing the options, then exit. Any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
>
> [*Bash Reference Manual*, **Invoking Bash**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash)

Obviously I can't replicate your setup, but here is [an MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that works fine for me in bash version 3 and 4:

```
#!/bin/bash    
make_noise() {
    echo "$1" "$1" "$1" "$1"
}
export -f make_noise
echo "foo bar" | xargs -I {} bash -c "make_noise '{}'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Now with `xargs` and `bash -c` I get the following error: `bash: compressor: command not found`.  I added `export -f` before executing `fswatch` and `xargs` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  I get no feedback when I substitute `xargs` with `parallel` even with the `-v` flag applied.  Is there another component to getting functions to work as arguments for a command?

Comment: It's working fine for me; see my edit for a minimal test case.

Comment: After tweaking it a little bit your original example worked great.  I haven't tried with parallel yet.  The only problem I have now is that fswatch monitors subdirectories recursively, so the original design of the script creates a loop of subdirectories.  I'm going to modify so that new files are sent to another folder that fswatch doesn't monitor.  I'll post the completed script when I'm done.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

compressor() {
    filepath="$1"
    mkdir -m 777 /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath##/}_PROCESSING
    mv ${filepath} /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath##/}_PROCESSING
    /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -computergroup "This Computer" -jobpath /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath##/}_PROCESSING/${filepath##/} -settingpath /Users/lr/Documents/CONVERTHQTEST.cmprstng -locationpath /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch/${filepath##/}_PROCESSING/${filepath%.*}.mp4
}

export -f compressor

/usr/local/Cellar/fswatch/1.8.0/bin/fswatch -0 -v --event Created --event MovedTo /Users/lr/Desktop/Watch |
    parallel -0 compressor
```